# How to do view 2nd page in paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, page-index-changed

I am able to view 1st page upon search but if data is more than 10 rows than its showing me full grid bind.

How can i view the 2nd page

```
 public void fncfillApplication()
    {
        try
        {


            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("Application.xml"));
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                gvApplication.DataSource = ds;
                gvApplication.DataBind();

            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();

        }
```

On page index I am applying paging and my datasource is xml

```
 protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gvApplication.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
       this.fncfillApplication();
    }
```

I am able to view my 1 st page when doing paging by clicking 1 but when click on 2nd page i get my full grid bind.

How would I able to see data further if PageSize="10" but data in grid is 20 rows.How to see last 10 rows.

Comment: If you have asked the same question here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302823/how-to-view-2nd-page-in-paging-on-click-numbers-in-bottom
 then close this one

Answer (score 0):

Set properties-

**EnablePaging**

EnablePaging property to True to get GridView Paging.

**PageSize**

Number of rows from the data source to display per page.

Comment: Please see this Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302823/how-to-view-2nd-page-in-paging-on-click-numbers-in-bottom