# How to view 2nd page in paging on click numbers in bottom

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I am trying to search and my grids shows me results of 20 records.

If i have applied allow paging true and page size is 20

Then on click on 2nd page in Grid my whole grid is refreshing ans showing me whole grid once again with its 1st page.

How do i view my last 10 records which are from 11 to 20 if records are 20 and page size is 10

Client side code of grid

```
<div id="divApplication" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvApplication"
        runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        AllowPaging="true"
        AllowSorting="True"
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
        PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
        OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging"
        CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped"
        PageSize="10" Width="50%">

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText='Application' HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="chkbox" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server"
                        att='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID")%>' Text='<%# SetLinkCodeApplication(Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID")),DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Application").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="3%" HorizontalAlign="left" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Binding my grid in C# on server side code

```
public void fncfillApplication()
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("Application.xml"));
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            gvApplication.DataSource = ds;
            gvApplication.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}

protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvApplication.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.fncfillApplication();
}
```

Setlinkcode for Binding my data in edit mode

```
public string SetLinkCodeApplication(Int64 sId, string sName)
{
    string functionReturnValue = null;
    try
    {
        functionReturnValue = "<a href=javascript:fncopenEditPopUpApplication(" + sId + ")>" + sName.Trim() + "</a>";
        //return functionReturnValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return functionReturnValue;
}
```

I am using Xml Datasource to bind data

Comment: Tested your code. It works just fine.

Comment: On searching it shows me 20 Results  but when i click on 2nd index  to view last 10 records binding happens again and show me all records

Comment: Its working fine but when search than if grid fills with 20 Records but if page size is 20 than I cant view last 10 records

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use

```
  XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\LINQtoXMLSelectApp\LINQtoXMLSelectApp\Employee.xml");
        var query = from r in document.Descendants("Employee") where (int)r.Element("Age") > 27 select new
        {
            FirstName = r.Element("FirstName").Value, Age = r.Element("Age").Value };
        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I am using .net framework 2.0   I doesn't support  LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not producing with me. It is working fine. I have used the following XML file to bind to gridview. Code and HTML is the same.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<Customer>  
  <Customerinfo>  
    <Name>Vithal Wadje</Name>  
    <city>Mumbai</city>  
    <Address>Sion, Mumbai</Address>  
 </Customerinfo>  
  <Customerinfo>  
    <Name>D Sudhir Wadje</Name>  
    <city>Latur</city>  
    <Address>Latur</Address>  
  </Customerinfo>  
  <Customerinfo>  
    <Name>U D</Name>  
    <city>Mumbai</city>  
    <Address>DN,Road Mumbai</Address>  
  </Customerinfo>  
  <Customerinfo>  
    <Name>Anil Kumar</Name>  
    <city>Delhi</city>
    <Address>Nehru House</Address>  
  </Customerinfo>  
<Customerinfo>  
    <Name>Five</Name>  
    <city>Mumbai</city>  
    <Address>Sion, Mumbai</Address>  
 </Customerinfo>  
<Customerinfo>  
    <Name>Six</Name>  
    <city>Mumbai</city>  
    <Address>Sion, Mumbai</Address>  
 </Customerinfo>  
<Customerinfo>  
    <Name>Seven</Name>  
    <city>Mumbai</city>  
    <Address>Sion, Mumbai</Address>  
 </Customerinfo>  
<Customerinfo>  
    <Name>Eight</Name>  
    <city>Mumbai</city>  
    <Address>Sion, Mumbai</Address>  
 </Customerinfo>  
<Customerinfo>  
    <Name>Nine</Name>  
    <city>Mumbai</city>  
    <Address>Sion, Mumbai</Address>  
 </Customerinfo>  
<Customerinfo>  
    <Name>Ten</Name>  
    <city>Mumbai</city>  
    <Address>Sion, Mumbai</Address>  
 </Customerinfo>  
<Customerinfo>  
    <Name>Eleven</Name>  
    <city>Mumbai</city>  
    <Address>Sion, Mumbai</Address>  
 </Customerinfo>
<Customerinfo>  
    <Name>Twelve</Name>  
    <city>Mumbai</city>  
    <Address>Sion, Mumbai</Address>  
 </Customerinfo>    
</Customer>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think its help you

```
ds.Tables[0].Select("ID=1 AND ID2=3");
```